# How old can fairies become?

Tags: seven-deadly-sins

In question 122 of Mugimeshi-san's question corner, somebody asked whether the fairy king's lifespan is longer than the rest of the fairies. Which gets answered with "*It might be the longest out of all the different species.*"

[image: question corner]

But how old can these fairies become?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of now, there's no official answer, but **at least older than 4200 years**.

Summarizing from the [Wikia](http://nanatsu-no-taizai.wikia.com/wiki/Fairy_Clan) about Fairy Clan:

> **Longevity**: The average lifespan of a Fairy is between 1000 to 1500 years. They do not appear to physically age and they never suffer from illness.

Now, comparing the known fairies' age:

- Invisible: ?
- Cisca: ?
- Dahlia: ? (former, 2nd king/queen)
- Melik: ?
- Elaine: ±1000
- Ende: 1000+
- Puora: 1000+
- Helbram: ±1300 (deceased)
- King: 1300+ (current king)
- Gloxinia: ±1400 (former, 1st king)
- Gerheade: ±4200

Although most of them are mentioned in between 1000-1500 range, Gerheade is an exception, and she's not even a king.

Thus, assuming there's nothing that prevents their natural aging (e.g. Elaine, Helbram), and since they don't suffer any illness, fairy king should even be possible to live more than 5000 years.

Comment: is Gloxinia ~1400 because he was sealed with the rest of Commandments?