# How is Gerheade still Alive?

Tags: seven-deadly-sins

Gerheade was alive during the Holy War 3,000 years ago. Since fairies only live for about 1,000 years, she logically should have died 2,000 years ago. So why is she still alive?

Comment: Related: [How old can fairies become?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/34426)

Comment: Did something change since I last visited this site? I'm trying to ask a question, but tags like "nanatsu-no-taizai" are missing.... Help?

Comment: Nothing changed, the tag is still there. If you have a problem with the site itself, please ask on the [meta] with [tag:support] tag and state the issue clearly.